# How to return a big number in a plain format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers, biginteger

I want to return a big number in a plain format but instead I'm getting this:

```
>>> x=1000000000000000000000000000000
>>> int(1*x/100) # try to get 1% of x
9999999999999999583119736832 # <------------ here
```

I was expecting `10000000000000000000000000000`, how do I achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use decimal to handle the decimal point more precisely.

It provides fast correctly-rounded decimal floating point arithmetic.  In contrast, numbers like 1.1 and 2.2 do not have exact representations in binary floating point. Decimal numbers can be represented exactly and  in decimal floating point.

```
from decimal import Decimal
x = Decimal(1000000000000000000000000000000)
print(int(1*x/100))  # 10000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: What do you get with this when you divide by 3 instead?

Comment: the decimal module has a user alterable precision (defaulting to 28 places) which can be as large as needed for a given problem.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist As it converts to int, they'd be better off simply using floor division. That gives better results (and is faster and less code).

Comment: @KellyBundy whats floor division?

Comment: Is using Decimal same as doing `int(1*x//100)` ? i am getting same result as @Lazyer

Comment: @dape11 https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations

Comment: @dape11 **int(1*x//100)** is little different with **"/"** operation.  **decimal** doesn't work with **"//"** operation.

Answer (score 2):

Floating point arithmetic has [Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html?highlight=floating).

In your case simply avoid it by using *integer division*:

```
>>> x=1000000000000000000000000000000
>>> x=x//100
>>> x
10000000000000000000000000000
```